Chat's site minilist widget is broken
All of the widgets which are used to select a network site, such as on the room creation page and parent site selector, only show undefined when a search query is typed in; clearing the query shows a long list of undefined. The endpoint which they use to read the site list seems okay, so this might be a frontend bug.
Room creation page:

Parent site:


One of the things that has changed with the upgrade is that we've consolidated the various JSON serialization methods. Turns out the new version has a slightly different default behavior when it comes to property casing.
Your browser was expecting something like {"Host": "codegolf.stackoverflow.com"}, but instead the server sent {"host": "codegolf.stackoverflow.com"} (note the lowercase "host").
Fixed now, thanks for the report!
